# Why does my Galaxy S now displays 'couldn't connect' when I press the microphone key

Tags: keyboard, voice-recognition

I have been entering numbers using the microphone key on the keyboard fine yesterday.

All of a sudden, when I tried to enter numbers with the microphone key some time later, the message 'couldn't connect' is displayed when I press the microphone key.

Anyone any idea how to fix this ? Restarting the phone, does not seem to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text-to-speech conversion in Android is all done on the cloud.  The phone sends in your recording and returns the speech.  You need to make sure you're connected to either 3G or Wifi for this to work.

Do other apps that require connections work?

Comment: That's it. I am not always connected - only when I am explicitly looking up things. The first time I was entering numbers like that, I obviously was connected. While later on, I obviously wasn't. Never occurred to me I should be looking in that direction to find the answer. Thanks.